# Is there some index of Ubuntu architecture/version number combinations?

Tags: versions

I wish to review all the Ubuntu versions released for each architecture.

Is there some historical list somewhere, or something similar, that shows what versions are available for what architectures?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is.

- http://releases.ubuntu.com/ and  http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases for most current
- http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ for old and unsupported ones.

Comment: Current releases for some architectures are at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/ rather than http://releases.ubuntu.com/. For example, images for Xenial are at http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/ and others are at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/xenial/release/. (The cdimage server also has less commonly used images for some of the same releases whose more commonly used images reside on the releases server, and has images for several official derivatives.) Each of the three sites and what they contain is briefly summarized in the text displayed at http://releases.ubuntu.com/.

Comment: @EliahKagan I wanted to add cdimage originally as well, but appeared similar to releases.ubuntu.com. Thanks for clarification

Comment: @EliahKagan  Already edited. Also,  I always welcome edits as long as they add information and value to the answer, which in this case it would :)